# Why is this line obfuscated?

Tags: c

In this snippet,

```
if(((RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType) & RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI) == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI)
{
    /* statements */
}
```

the member `OscillatorType` could have any of the values, or their combination, defined below.

```
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_NONE            ((uint32_t)0x00000000)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE             ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI             ((uint32_t)0x00000002)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE             ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI             ((uint32_t)0x00000008)
```

Why is the `if` written this way? Why not simply like this?

`if(RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI)`

Comment: the data type of `RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType` might not be `uint32_t`.

Comment: still, comparing it to itself makes no sense, if the bit is off, then it would just be 0, so why add the "==" part

Comment: What's obfuscated about that? This is the standard idiom for testing that a certain bit *and only that* certain bit is set.

Comment: @captainsomewhere you should add another word to your assertion: the member `OscillatorType` could have any *combination* of the values defined below.

Comment: @datenwolf true, except for the "*and only that certain bit*" part.

Comment: @Sourav The datatype is indeed uint32_t; a group of bits packed in an integer. As has been made clear now...

Comment: @Guiroux Yeah that too, now that you mention... Arjun's answer makes sense.

Comment: @datenwolf It just appeared to be. It just seemed unlikely that `RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType` would have a combination of these values.

Comment: @Weather Vane Done. This half answers the question now... :-P

Comment: @captainsomewhere in this example, 3 of the bits are set with `RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48;`. https://github.com/mbedmicro/mbed/issues/636

Comment: @Weather Vane - Thanks! They seem to have turned OFF one of the oscillators next. I'll keep this for later. I'm just this far into reading about this. Still not sure why define two types for the Oscillator at the same time.

Comment: @captainsomewhere they probably specify its *properties*.

Comment: @CássioRenan: Uh, that extra `==` on the end is there for the "and just that bit" thing. Think that code through: What would happen if another bit in addition to `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI` was set? This kind of test as above you can find a lot in embedded application code. For example this snippet most like comes from the clock initialization of a STMF32 controller.

Comment: @datenwolf it would be set to zero by the & operator(because it is zero in `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI`) and the result would still equal `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI`. To test for *only that bit*, a simple `==` without the bitwise AND would be more appropriate.

Comment: @datenwolf Reading again you comment, I think the problem is the ambiguity in the sentence. You meant "check if that bit is the only one set in the input" or "check only that bit, ignoring the others"? :)

Comment: @CássioRenan: The former one. If I'd had meant the later I'd have written "test if a particular bit among others is set".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType` is a collection of bits packed in an integer value, each bit representing one of the values (`RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE`, ...). That's why they come in powers of 2. The code you showed just checks if the bit associated with `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI` is set. It's very probable that bits of other values are also set.

For example if the binary representation of `OscillatorType` is `0...011`, the first and second bit is set, meaning that the `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE` and `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI` values are selected.

Answer (score 3):

Because it may have any of these values **at the same time**. The `&` (bitwise AND) operator is serving the purpose of extracting only the value `RCC_OSCILLATOR_TYPE_HSI`.

As an example, your input may look like this:

```
010011
```

While `RCC_OSCILLATOR_TYPE_HSI` looks like this:

```
000010
```

The AND operator with these two values will return `000010`, witch exactly equals `RCC_OSCILLATOR_TYPE_HSI`.

However, if your input looks like this:

```
110101
```

The bitwise AND operator between this and `RCC_OSCILLATOR_TYPE_HSI` will return `0`, and the condition will be `false`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very common C idiom and not obfuscated in any way. Those are two very different tests.

```
if ((RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType & RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI) == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI)
```

says "if the `RCC_OSCILLATOR_HSI` bit is 1". It doesn't care whether any of the other bits are 0 or 1, whereas

```
if (RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI)
```

says "if the `RCC_OSCILLATOR_HSI` bit is 1 *AND* all the other bits are 0".

Comment: OP was asking why not `if (RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType & RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI)` ?

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan - I don't believe that's the case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure why `RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType` could have a combination of the values though.

Comment: @Arjun Nope. I meant why not `==`. Since I still find it unlikely it would have a combination of the values and hence a direct comparison seemed straightforward. Thanks for pointing out why only `&` should not be used though.

Comment: @captainsomewhere - Without  knowing more about the codebase, this is just a wild guess. Perhaps it was originally written with the intent that it could have more than one value, but it turned out that case would never happen. Even if the original programmer realized this, they may have decided not to make what could potentially be a large (and dangerous) change to the codebase. Sometimes the answer to "why?" is simply human fallibility and/or inertia.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` condition is interested only in the second last bit of `RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType`.  So `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI` is used as a mask and then compared to itself.

If you see all the constants, first one is all zeroes where as the others have its set bit at successive positions.

Now, doing `&` with any of these constants can tell you whether its corresponding bit is set in the said parameter.

If you want to set all of the possible values, you would be doing:

```
RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI;
```

Why comparison using `==`?

That's not required and makes the code cluttered. I think that the programmer wanted to bring uniformity when testing for `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_NONE`.

The programmer can't test for `RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType & RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_NONE` because that would evaluate to `zero`. You are either forced to negate the condition just for this check.

Comment: but when mask is used, if the `RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI` bit is off, then `RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType` is 0 , so you don't need the "==" part right ?

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_NONE            ((uint32_t)0x00000000)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE             ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI             ((uint32_t)0x00000002)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE             ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI             ((uint32_t)0x00000008)  

int main(void)
{
    /* set HSI and HSE */
    uint32_t flags = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE | RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI; 

    if (flags == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI) {
        puts("flags = HSI");
    }
    if ((flags & RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI) == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI) {
        puts("HSI is set in flags");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
HSI is set in flags
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, `==` is not equivalent with `&`. Because `==` looks at the whole 32 bit register, including any crap you aren't interested in. While `&` just looks at the relevant parts.

And the `&` is simple binary arithmetic for bitwise AND. In my opinion, you need to understand binary numbers before even enrolling your first programmer course, but maybe that's just me.

Anyway, given that you actually understand what bitwise AND does, it would have made more sense if you had code like

```
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE                 ((uint32_t)0x0000000F) // mask
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_NONE            ((uint32_t)0x00000000)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE             ((uint32_t)0x00000001)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI             ((uint32_t)0x00000002)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE             ((uint32_t)0x00000004)
#define RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI             ((uint32_t)0x00000008) 

...

(RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType & RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE) == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI
```

Maybe this is what the programmer of that code intended, but they didn't quite manage to bring the code all the way there.

Comment: I'm missing something. Suppose, for example, if the objective is to check whether the HSI bit is set whereas actually, both HSI and HSE bits are set (`RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType` contains `0x00000003`) then `(RCC_OscInitStruct->OscillatorType & RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE) == RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI` evaluates to a `FALSE`? Assuming of course that I understand bitwise AND.

Comment: @captainsomewhere If both bits could be set at the same time then it would probably not make sense to have such a "group mask". Because in that case you'd have to write `(type & groupmask) & bitmask`, which is the very same thing as `type & bitmask`.